References for discrete curvature
I'm wondering if anyone knows references on discrete curvature (eg. the content in this playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9_jI1bdZmz0hIrNCMQW1YmZysAiIYSSS).
Thank You!

Have you tried the reference the author suggests in the youtube video? https://brickisland.net/DDGSpring2024/

Thanks for sharing. The notes https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf are good but I don't see any textbooks/papers (unless I'm just missing it)

Have you looked through the references on page 162 of the notes?
